# MFC C++ using static member and compiling issue

Tags: c++, oop, mfc, encapsulation

I have a class Rules() that have a static public member called m_String.
I define that member in the class with a proper CString.
When i want to use that member from a global function, i use "Rules::m_String"
when compiling i get the following error:

> Rules.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class ATL::CStringT > > Rules::m_String" (?m_String@Rules@@2V?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@A)

maybe this means that the function inside Rules that set m_String should be static also ?

Comment: What is means is that your code is likely wrong. Would you like us to guess what your code looks like?

Comment: are you sure you are not confusing declaration and definition?

Comment: No! Functions accessing `Rules::m_String`don't need to be static. The error says the symbol isn't defined and can't be linked!

Comment: hello, i dont like this -1 for not showing code since it is weekend and we on israel dont work i didnt see you request for a code.. never mind have a good week

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you don't have an instance of `Rules::m_String` defined (**not declared**) and initialized in your `Rules.cpp` compilation unit.

Do you have a line like the following in your `Rules.cpp` outside any function definitions?

```
CString Rules::m_String = CString("Whatever initial value required");
```

Anything else is hard to say without you have shown more code.